# How to publish a Netbeans Update Center on Java.net?

Tags: netbeans, updates

I created a NetBeans based application and I want t publish its update center in the Java.net project's page. Any idea on how to do this?

The page suggests using Webdav but is not working.

Edit:

I was able to do it by adding then in a folder in the downloads section but it is a manual process. Any easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have done it so far is loading all the files into a folder one by one, manually. I just hoped for a better way.